# Reading data from Word (.docx) or HTM file and uploading to mysql DB using PHP

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli, web-scraping

I am making a multiple choice question answer database - where the question and answers have images as well. The Q&A is in a word document. So I am trying to read the data and upload in the database.

**What I have done till now :**
I have converted the word file to HTM file, so the images are now stored in a folder and the HTM file have the path and filename to that. My HTM file looks kinda like that (this is one question with option and other info):

```
<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:137%;color:windowtext'>I.16) </span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:137%;color:windowtext'>Q.16) </span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:137%;color:windowtext'><img width=419
height=288 id="Picture 2" src="20180808_files/image001.jpg"></span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:137%;color:windowtext'>*[1] 13</span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:137%;color:windowtext'>[2] 17</span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:137%;color:windowtext'>[3] 84</span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:137%;color:windowtext'>[4] 98</span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:137%;color:windowtext'>[MARKS] 2</span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:137%;color:windowtext'>[NEGATIVE MARKS] 0.5</span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:137%;color:windowtext'>[TAG] General
Intelligence and Reasoning</span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:137%;color:windowtext'>[DIFFICULTY] Easy</span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:137%;color:windowtext'>[ANSWER TIME] 0</span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:137%;color:windowtext'>[QUESTION TYPE]
Multi_choice</span></p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='line-height:137%;background:white'><span
style='font-size:12.0pt;line-height:137%;color:windowtext'>[SOLUTION]</span></p>
```

Now here is my php code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["Upload"]))
    {
        $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
        {
        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
             while (($htmData = fgets($file, 10000)) !== FALSE)
             {
              print_r($htmData);
             }
         fclose($file);
    }
    else
        echo 'Invalid File';
}
?>
```

I am getting clean document like this in print_r, But now I need to get only the question and answers in an array so that I can insert in the DB. but not sure how to get rid of the [CAPITAIZED INFOS] and others.

```
I.16)

Q.16)
/img path


*[1] 13

[2] 17

[3] 84

[4] 98

[MARKS] 2

[NEGATIVE MARKS] 0.5

[TAG] General Intelligence and Reasoning

[DIFFICULTY] Easy

[ANSWER TIME] 0

[QUESTION TYPE] Multi_choice

[SOLUTION]
```

Comment: you can leverage [this library](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) to read the word file and then decide how to handle the content.

Comment: Thanks, will surely look into it. But If I can only the question and options in arrays that will be better for me.